# How to edit a node graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

With `d3js` it is possible to visualize node graphs, like [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/MoritzStefaner/1377729)

[image]

Now I would like to let the user interact with the graph. It must be possible to:

- create/delete nodes and edges
- attach data to a node/edge, by clicking on it.
- push the data to the server, so that it can be made persistent

Is it possible to do that with `d3js`? Is there any other tool which offers this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, all of these things are relatively easy to do with `d3`.  You can see lots of different examples of force directed graphs at http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock.  Here are a couple that you might find useful:

Adding nodes and edges to a graph:

- http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/929623
- http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347

Loading data from an XML file to create a layout

- http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1080941

Listening for mouse over

- http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2706022

From personal experience I would say that `d3` would be the best tool for doing this sort of thing.  I'd suggest playing around with it a bit and then asking more specific questions when you have them.